# Either behave in or just behave

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference in the following two sentences

> The way he is **behaving in**, he'll soon spill the beans. I am afraid.

> The way he is **behaving**, he'll soon spill the beans. I am afraid.

Is any one of them wrong?

Comment: If you wanted to keep the preposition in the first version above, it would have to be transformed into *The way **in which** he is behaving...*

Comment: @Fumble But why? Can you give me a reason?

Comment: I'd have to think about that. But note that *strictly speaking*, you text isn't a valid "sentence" (even though the *second* version is perfectly idiomatic). That initial element before the comma is really just a ***noun phrase***, with no valid syntactic connection to the ***statement*** that follows. That may not be directly relevant to the question of when and where the preposition ***in*** is required or not, but it *might* be simpler to analyse an utterance where that noun phrase validly acts as the syntactic "subject" - ***The way he behaves [in]** annoys me.*

Answer (score -1):

"Behave in" is not an idiom.  One would have to "behave in some manner."

Comment: "Behave" implies behaving properly. "Misbehave" means behaving improperly.

Comment: There are a lot of manners even within propriety.

Comment: This answer might address the matter of why it's not syntactically valid idiomatic to include the final preposition in ***The teacher told the children to behave [in]***, but that's not the question OP is asking about here.